Aliases working in subjective conditions on Mac
I'm currently working on a dotfiles configuration (which runs zsh) which I've been using on my mini home server and and Linux CLIs on my PC. I've also utilised it on my work Macbook which runs MacOS, but noticed I was running into some weird issues.
(($+commands[terraform])) && {
    alias tf="terraform" 
}

The above code is part of my alias file for zsh, which maps 'tf' to the terraform command. The issue I've been running to is, that this does not work on the Mac terminal; in which I get the "'tf' command not found error" (or along the lines), but does in the VS Code intergrated terminal. Further adding confusion, I have 'g' mapped to git, and it works perfectly on both Mac terminal and VS Code intergrated terminal.
Any ideas or help would be great. Thanks

What exactly does "does not work" mean here (complete your question with the exact error messages etc.)  It is not clear that you are using zsh in your terminal when you say it's "not working".  Is "mac" the same as "macOS", or are you running some other Unix on Apple hardware?

@Kusalananda - I will update the initial post, but basically, the error I get is "tf command not found"; which is not an issue in the VS Code terminal. My Mac is running MacOS to yes

Likely the problem is that the quoted line is in an init file that is not always run, but information about the specific location of this was not given in the question.

$+commands[terraform] expands to 1 if there's an element with key terraform in the $commands special associative array which maps command names to their path, and 0 otherwise.
((arithmetic expression)) returns false if the arithmetic expression resolves to 0 (or 0.) and true otherwise, so (($+commands[terraform])) returns true iff terraform is a known (external, not builtin, alias, function...) command to the shell.
The $commands special associative array exposes the internal command hash table, the same one that the hash / rehash / unhash builtin commands operate on by default and that is filled up automatically when the shell looks up commands in directories of the $path array (tied to the colon separated $PATH standard environment variable).
That special associative array comes with the zsh/parameter dynamically loadable module but in current versions of zsh, that module is loaded automatically when the variable is dereferenced.
$ zsh -xfc 'zmodload; print -r - $commands[ls]; zmodload'
+zsh:1> zmodload
zsh/main
+zsh:1> print -r - /usr/bin/ls
/usr/bin/ls
+zsh:1> zmodload
zsh/main
zsh/parameter

That is not the case when zsh is emulating other shells like when it's called as sh, ksh, csh, or with --emulate sh/ksh/csh, but I would expect you'd get some errors in those emulation modes when interpreting that zsh-specific code.
Even if the internal command hash table has not been populated yet, upon first reference of $commands, it will be populated. It's also regenerated when $path/$PATH is modified.
So if your tf alias was not defined, that would indicate that at the time (($+commands[terraform])) was run, no directory in the value of $path at the time contained a file called terraform. You could add a typeset -p path just before that line to see what value it has at that point.
In any case, an alias is just some text replaced with some other text when found in command position, so the terraform command doesn't have to exist (as a command or otherwise such as builtin, function...) for you to be able to define it, so you could as well unconditionally define it:
alias tf=terraform

You could also make it a function rather than an alias:
tf() terraform "$@"

In either case, if the terraform command doesn't exist at the time tf is run later on, you'll get an error that the terraform command doesn't exist.
BTW, I would rather write your code:
if (( $+commands[terraform] )) alias tf=terraform

Using condition && action is a poor replacement for a proper if construct. In zsh which has short forms of if, it's not even shorter. It means that if the condition is false, the whole condition && action is falsy which primes $? with a non-zero value.

Thanks for the insights! I just ran typeset -p PATH on my Macbook, and I just realised that I had installed Terraform via brew, and it wasn't adding it to my path. Which makes sense cause a few other aliases were failing
